# git p4 clone not getting all files for @rev,#head

Tags: git, git-p4

I try to clone a p4 repo from the middle because it is a huge repo with long history so @all is not an option.

The problem is some files are missing from the working copy because they were added before my starting revision.

Using #head directly does not have this problem (i.e.: git p4 clone //depot)

For example,
There is a file added under //depot/misc/file.txt at revision 123456
Latest revision is 400000

When I do "git p4 clone //depot" I get all files from the #head ("git p4 clone //depot@all" will have the file and all history, obviously)

When I do "git p4 clone //depot@250000,#head" I do not get the //depot/misc/file.txt.

What should I do to get it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but maybe clone the base revision `git p4 clone //depot@250000` then `git p4 rebase` all the more recent changes?

Comment: Thanks! That works. I remember I tried that in the past (likely 1.9.4) and it was not working that way, it locked to only that revision. Maybe I didn't do it right back then or memory is playing tricks on me. :)